# spark-submit job by doing exec on a master pod in k8s

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, exec

I have successfully created spark cluster on kubernetes with 1 master and 2 worker pods. The spark v2.4.3 running with Java 8 and scala 2.11.12 on k8s with kubectl v1.16.0 and minikube v1.4.0.

For detailed `kubectl get pods` shows this -

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
spark-master-fcfd55d7d-qrpsw    1/1     Running   0          66m
spark-worker-686bd57b5d-6s9zb   1/1     Running   0          65m
spark-worker-686bd57b5d-wrqrd   1/1     Running   0          65m
```

I am also able  run built-in spark application such as `pyspark` and `spark-shell` by `exec`ing the master pod -

```
kubectl exec spark-master-fcfd55d7d-qrpsw -it spark-shell`
```

Since I already have enough env I am trying to run my spark job on this like above. But it is not working. The spark submit command looks like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

spark-submit \
   --class com.cloudian.spark.main.RequestInfoLogStreamer \
   /Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/target/scala-2.11/scala-spark-streaming_2.11-1.0.jar
```

And the `.sh` script is then submitted to master pod -

```
kubectl exec spark-master-fcfd55d7d-qrpsw /Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/logstreamer.sh
```

But this is giving me error -

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/logstreamer.sh\": stat /Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/logstreamer.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126
```

What am I doing wrong here? My intention is to get the work done by these master and worker nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read from the error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/logstreamer.sh\": stat /Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/logstreamer.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
>   command terminated with exit code 126

What interest us the most is part `/Users/atekade/IdeaProjects/scala-spark-streaming/logstreamer.sh: no such file or directory`, which means the pod is unable to locate the `logstreamer.sh` file.

Script `logstreamer.sh` needs to be uploaded to the `spark-master` pod.
Also the `scala-spark-streaming_2.11-1.0.jar` needs to be there as well.

You can configure a [PersistenVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/), this will be useful because if your pod will ever be rescheduled all data that was not stored on a PV will be lost.

Here is a link to [minikube documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/persistent_volumes/) for Persistent Volumes.

You can also use different [Storage Classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).